# Outdated value issue in JavaScript form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here's the HTML:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Answer..." id="ansbox1">
<input type="submit" onclick="submit1();" id="sp1">
```

Here's my JS:

```js
var txt1 = document.getElementById("ansbox1").value;
    
function submit1() {
  if (txt1.split(" ").join("") === atob("[base64string]").split(" ").join("")) {
    alert("Yaay!");
  }
  else { 
    alert("Nope, its wrong!");
  }
}
```

When I put (even the decoded matching string) in the input box, it still always shows "Nope, its wrong!".

Any error?

I referred to this, yet I still get the same issue...
[JS - Check if the input field equals the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731946/js-check-if-the-input-field-equals-the-solution)

Comment: I feel your `txt1`, being outside the function, has old/stale data. Try putting it inside the function call

Comment: That fixed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `txt1` is outside the function call, it has stale data. Put it inside the function call, so it can be updated everytime.

```
function submit1() {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById("ansbox1").value;
  if (txt1.split(" ").join("") === atob("[base64string]").split(" ").join("")) {
    alert("Yaay!");
  }
  else {alert("Nope, its wrong!");}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `txt1` variable is outside the function, which could have a stale/previous value due to scope.
This variable should be put inside the function so that it's always updated:

```js
function submit1() {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById("ansbox1").value;

  if (txt1.split(" ").join("") === atob("[base64string]").split(" ").join("")) {
    alert("Yaay!");
  }
  else {
    alert("Nope, its wrong!");
  }
}
```